# How to access an ansible block variable in a file from the same block

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I define a yml variable files for ansible with the following structure:

```
appserver:
   root_directory: C:\app
   config_directory: '{{ root_directory }}\config'
```

it seems the second variable `config_directory` cannot be interpreted correctly, I get a `VARIABLE NOT FOUND ERROR`.

I tried with:

```
appserver:
   root_directory: C:\app
   config_directory: '{{ appserver.root_directory }}\config'
```

It does not work either, I have a very long trace of error, the most interesting part is :

```
recursive loop detected in template string:{{ appserver.root_directory }}\config
```

When I use double quotes instead of simple quotes,

appserver:
       root_directory: C:\app
       config_directory: "{{ appserver.root_directory }}\config"

I get the following error:

```
 The offending line appears to be:

 app_root: D:\WynsureEnvironments\Application
 wynsure_root: "{{ appserver.root_directory }}\config"
                                              ^ here
 We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
 missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
 start a value. For instance:

with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

When using variable blocks, how can I reuse variables to assign new variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use such a recursive jinja2 variable declaration in ansible.

Here are 2 (non exhaustive list) alternative solutions:

1. Don't use a hash. Prepend your vars names. You will typically find this type of naming conventions in e.g. reusable roles on [ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/)

```
appserver_root_directory: C:\app
appserver_config_directory: '{{ appserver_root_directory }}\config'
```

2. If you really need a hash of this kind, declare a "private" variable outside of your hash and reuse it inside.

```
_appserver_root: C:\app
appserver:
  root_directory: "{{ _appserver_root }}"
  config_directory: "{{ _appserver_root }}\config"
```

Comment: The mistake is in my post on stackoverflow, I do put the quotes (simple quotes though), and it does not work. I will try with double quotes.

Comment: With the simple quotes, I get an error, like "recursive loop detected."

Comment: `it does not work`, `It does not even parse with double quotes` => please edit your post and show us the errors. Also please take the time to read ["how do I create a minimal reproducible example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your contents on my first read. You cannot use this type of recursive declaration in jinja2. Updating my answer with alternatives.

Comment: it seems I cannot use a variable of a block in the same block, right?

Comment: No, because it is a recursive call (e.g. you are trying to calculate the content of your `appserver` hash while.... already calculating its content....).

Comment: Ok understood, but it's a setback to describe paths like that. Can I use ansible variables in json files?